# Not writing to HTML with jQuery and Mustache.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

I'm sure this is a combination of a cold plus a lack of sleep, but I'm stuck.

The code couldn't be much simpler:

```
$.get('template.tpl', function(tpl) {
    $.getJSON('json/data2.json', function(data) {
        var html = Mustache.render(tpl, data);
        $('#output').html(html);
    });
});
```

Tadaa. If I toss a `Console.Log(html)` on the line after it's declared, it outputs correctly... but for the life of me I can't solve why it's not placing the text into #output like it should. A free-standing `$('#output').html("foo");` outside of fething template.tpl works no problem.

Help?

**Solved**

Solved, thanks to a question from asgoth. Had the code right - had script tags surrounding the template in my .tpl file. They weren't needed any more, since the template was being pushed directly to Mustache... but were being written to the HTML, meaning I couldn't see the result.

I'm going for a nap.

Comment: Can you add the result of the console.log? Is data a string or a json object?

Comment: No need - that did the trick. Thanks. Had `script` tags in the template file since I grabbed the template directly from the original .htm. It was loading - but since it was inside of a script tag, I couldn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't use Mustache before, but shouldn't you use [`compile`](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)?

```
var html = Mustache.compile(tpl)(data);
```

Comment: It's actually Mustache.render... copy/paste from an old code block to try to rule out problems. Good catch. Thanks.